# Clearing history in BlazorWebView

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

In my MAUI application, I have a BlazorWebView like this:

```
<BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local: Main}" />
    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
</BlazorWebView>
```

How can I clear the history in this `BlazorWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built in support for this. You need to use the `PlatformView`. In Android and Windows, you can do like this:

```
public void ClearHistory()
{
#if ANDROID
    var webview = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
    webview?.ClearHistory();
#elif WINDOWS
    var webview = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
    _ = webview.CoreWebView2?.Profile.ClearBrowsingDataAsync(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds.BrowsingHistory);
#endif
}
```